# How to I get who did not receive the news?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this tables, and I need who hasn't got an email. I have a `news` table where is the news... And I have `emails` where is the registered emails. And I have `sendedmails` where can I see which news sent to any emails.

https://ibb.co/cXS0p5d here is my database.

Comment: Please provide a example see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `not exists`:

```
select e.*
from emails e
where not exists (select 1
                  from sendemails se
                  where se.email_id = e.id
                 );
```

Comment: no :( I need Who did not receive what news? In this query you can see Who got the news? https://ibb.co/7zDxxnT

Answer (score 0):

You can use not in:

```
select se.* from sendemails se where  se.new_id not in 
              (Select n.id from news n);
```

Comment: not good because once you get the news  more will not be in the query

Comment: You can see my tables here.
https://ibb.co/wJTYtgx
https://ibb.co/Y7JG5G1
https://ibb.co/s9CVcmX

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set